# Java ClassPath.from Guava problem - scanning windows/sys32 directory

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader, guava

I try to run this piece of code from eclipse and I see something strange. I am running on a windows machine with W10 installed with J8. 
When running this code the  ClassPath.from(...) function from Google Guava lib start to scan directory like "Cannot read directory C:\ProgramData\Packages" and takes very long and I don't understand why.

The Yaml.class file is from a thirdparty jar.

```
  ClassPath cp = ClassPath.from(Yaml.class.getClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case is that I had another library called batik (batik-xml.jar) that has in manifest "\" defined as path. The Guava Classpath.from scans each path find into the manifests and in this case scans C:\.